# Top indentation in Lightning experience tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, css, tab

Does Lightning experience guarantee that the body of the tab will always indent 90px from top? If the value is not guaranteed, then how would I be able to get it in code?

[image]

**In order to avoid `x-y problem`**.

I need this so that I would be able to implement fixed side bar on the left. The *cyan* color part on the left should take the whole height it can and have all parts visible (the bottom should not go below the bottom of the browser page and the top should not go under the lightning header with tabs above) at the same time. And when the user scrolls the *cyan* color part on the left should not violate restrictions just described (go below page or under the tabs header). I am using `position: sticky` for the purpose. And there are actually two problems I face here: the one is about getting the header height (the question is about it) and another is about getting the height of the browser page with the header height subtracted. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jz1yvr/6031/) is a js fiddle of what I am trying to do for those who are interested.

Comment: Why can not you relate your content based on section? Personally I remember that in case if you enable Utility Bar, it will be 100%-140px (or something similar)

Comment: I don't think there's way to get the value, but that 90px, to be honest, is there almost a year. In our use case, we had to show popovers dynamically relative to the clicked anchor tag in a custom Lightning component running in LEX, we kind of hardcoded that 90px in the code solved the positioning issue.

Comment: As you can see this is under element.style{top:...} and it's set using JavaScript and for.

Comment: @kurunve, I updated the question. I might help you understand my intentions.

Comment: @Praveen, that is a bad practice if the documentation does not guarantee the `90px` to be there forever.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, sorry, but I do not completely understand your point. ( :

Comment: It's alright, I just tried to do it with JS, Have a look :-)

Comment: @iloveseven Agreed!. I'd love to see a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of below JS logic you can get the top height dynamically:

**component.cmp**

```
<!--Top component required/needed things -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"  />

<aura:attribute name="topHeight" type="String" default="" />


<div aura:id="container">
    <!-- Your markup -->
    Top Height: {!v.topHeight}
</div>
<!-- Ending part -->
```

**componentController.js**

```
onInit: function(c, e, h){
  window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function () {
    try {
      var container = c.find('container');
      var bounds = container.getElement().getBoundingClientRect();
      c.set('v.topHeight', (bounds.top + 'px'));
    } catch (err) { }
  }), 250);
}
```

Comment: lol. let me try and I will be back

Comment: Sure, give it a try, and share your experience. ;-)

Comment: For some reasons `getElement()` return **null**. Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Please make sure the aura:id="..." is the one you are using inside the JS part and also the component I use c for sort.

Comment: Oh. You are using the `setTimeout` to tackle the **null** issue. That is dangerous. I am sorry, I can`t accept your answer, because it is even more dangerous than hardcoding the value. The platform does not guarantee that the custom component will be drawn in 250ms.

Comment: Yes, without this we can't confirm this will work everytime, but with the `setTimeout` it will work.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 You need to do this in `afterRender`. There's no guarantee the DOM will be present when `init` handler.

Comment: But there is nothing very complex that will take too much time in rendering and this element we are referencing in JS will be the root element.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 But still the `afterRender` is the right place to do it. Framework guarantees DOM availability if you use it there.

Comment: Sure @Praveen will implement in that way only, thank you :-)